# SQL Error: ORA-02017: integer value required

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to create a table in Oracle 11g. This is a backup table of already existing table which has `NVARCHAR2(382.5)` column in that.

But, when I am trying to create another backup table using `create` command, I am getting this error -

```
SQL Error: ORA-02017: integer value required
02017. 00000 -  "integer value required"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

This is my create statement,

```
CREATE TABLE "MYSCHEMA"."BACKUPTABLE"
(
INPUT_FILE_NAME                     NVARCHAR2(382.5)
);
```

Why is that table was already created with that datatype and now its not allowing?

Comment: How do you have a table with a column that has half a character?  Something seems wrong.  Just uses `nvarchar2(383)`.

Comment: You most definitely do **not** have a table with a  `NVARCHAR2(382.5)` column. That's impossible. Whatever software generated that SQL has a bug in it

Answer (score 0):

There is something else at play here. An NVARCHAR column requires an integer parameter. You cannot have a fraction of a character.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create backup table then you can use follows:

```
create table <name_for_backup_table> as select * from <raw_table>
```

So that all the columns of the table to get the correct types. And not have to write another query to copy raw data.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same thing, believe it has something to do with 32 bits and 64 bits client.

Just installed 18C 32 bits Oracle client on my Windows 10:

1) If connect using sqlplus and run a desc, the column showed as NVARCHAR2(255);

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
TITLE                                              NVARCHAR2(255)
```

2) If connect using "SQL Developer" and run desc there, the column showed NVARCHAR2(382.5)

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
TITLE                                              NVARCHAR2(382.5)
```

Might want to check with Oracle but it is not a real issue, so ...